# How to make an image slideshow with JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, slideshow

Is it possible? If the answer is no, any other ideas?

The list of pictures is dynamic, it depends on what user you're viewing.
How can I make a slideshow with the images that user uploaded?

Now it's working this way:
A single picture is displayed and you need to close it to open the next one.

```
<rich:dataGrid  id="albumGrid" value="#{someBean.pictures}" var="item" columns="4" elements="4" width="450px" rendered="#{not empty someBean.pictures}" style="margin-left:20px;">

                <a4j:commandLink id="fullLinkProfile">
                    <a4j:actionparam name="pic" value="#{item.path}" assignTo="#{picsBean.path}" />
                    <h:graphicImage value="/home/pictures/user/#{item.path}" rendered="#{item.path != null}"/>
                </a4j:commandLink>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <rich:datascroller for="albumGrid" boundaryControls="hide" stepControls="show"  fastControls="hide" >                       
                    </rich:datascroller>
                </f:facet>              

</rich:dataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any javascript slideshow function and pass bean value argument to it which has comma(,) seperated values of image paths.

Using [jQuery](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/) will give you best effects.

Also check [this](http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery).

Use following function to create your html code passing bean value and then integrate with any of jQuery plugin.

```
function loadImage(imgPaths)
{
    var images = imgPaths;
    var imgArr=images.split(",");
    var ulobj=document.getElementById("parentDiv");
    var i;
    var len =imagePath_array.length-1;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        var imgObj=document.createElement("img");
        var liObj=document.createElement("li");
        imgObj.src=imgArr[i];
        liObj.appendChild(imgObj);
        ulobj.appendChild(liObj);
    }
}
```